# Storing images in MongoDB using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm creating an online shop project. I'm using node.js express and mongoDB( mongoose )for back-end and React-redux for front-end...I wanna to know how I should store images and video files. Should I store them in mongoDB or local disk? which one is recommended in real project? Could you suggest me tutorial that helps me?

Comment: Did you try to Google it first? There are plenty of resources, including from SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use MongoDB's GridFS feature to store binary content

Refer : https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-upload-store-images-mongodb/

Comment: Thank you so much. could you refer me to a tutorial storing image in folder and save its path in database?

Comment: hi @Gandom  I suggest you to store the path of the image (image's metadata) into a MongoDB collection and the image's binary data into MongoDB GridFS.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.. This link https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-upload-store-images-mongodb/ helped me

Answer (score 0):

You can try hosting the images and videos on another platform like [ImageShack](http://imageshack.us/) or
[PhotoBucket](http://www.photobucket.com/), and save the links to them instead.